# JSF polling calls backend too often

Tags: jsf, primefaces, polling

I am using JSF with Primefaces and using poll to update a table periodically. The following code shows a simplified version of my current code:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:datatable id="customerTable" var="customer" value="#{dashboard.customers}">
        [...]
    </p:datatable>

    <p:poll interval="5" update="form:customerTable" />
</h:form>
```

The update is done every 5 seconds as expected. But the problem is that the `customerTable` seems to be loaded several times per update. 
My code in the backing bean which is called by the `#{dashboard.customers}` is as follows:

```
public List<Customer> getCustomers()
{
    LOG.debug("TEST");
    return customerService.loadCustomerList();
}
```

When I reload the page `getCustomers()` is called once, but via the polling it is called several times. Why is it called so often? Is the polling defined incorrectly?

Comment: I'm surprise that the `getCustomers` method is only called once without polling. How are you sure? Also read the excellent explanation of BalusC about [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2090062/913543).

Comment: Thought about this lifecycle handling, but as it was called only once on page reload seemingly, I assumed that I implemented the polling mechanism wrong. Thanks for the link. I need to change my code accordingly :)